# Run-Length encoding image compression in Java

Tags: java, image-processing, image-compression, run-length-encoding

Okay so i've got a University assignment where I need to compress an image using both Run-length encoding and huffman encoding. I'm focusing on the Run-Length encoding atm since I don't think i'm going to have time to implement the huffman.

What I am currently doing is passing in a buffered image, Then doing

```
public byte[] byteArray(BufferedImage image){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] imageInByte = null;
    try{
        ImageIO.write(image, "BMP", baos);
        baos.flush();
        imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
        baos.close();
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    return imageInByte;
}
```

to get the byte's of the image.
I then take that and do the actual compression, to do this atm I'm using a stringBuffer which I'm pretty sure is wrong but I can't think of another way to do it. so the code for that is

```
public String getRunLength(){
    StringBuffer dest = new StringBuffer();        
    for(int i =0; i < imageByteArray.length; i++){
        int runlength = 1;
        while(i+1 < imageByteArray.length && imageByteArray[i] == imageByteArray[i+1]){
            runlength++;
            i++;

        }     


        dest.append(runlength);  

        dest.append(imageByteArray[i]);

    }
    return dest.toString();
}
```

I'm pretty sure I shouldn't be converting to a string since when I go back to the bytes then I will be getting the ascii values rather than the actual bytes. But I can't figure out how I would go about appending the run length to a standard Byte Array efficiently (I think I could do it if I appended the run length to the start, then moved everything after byte[i+runLength] down runLength amount in the array.. but that would be extremely inefficient and prone to error... probably)

I then need to save it as an image, which obviously isn't working at the moment but the code i've currently got for that is

```
 try{
        File newImage = new File("Saved.png");
        ImageIO.write(rleImage, "BMP", newImage);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("something fucked up");
    }
```

Thanks for any help you might be able to provide :)

Just noticed I missed out the part where I set the rleImage that is done like

```
 public BufferedImage stringToImage(String runLengthEncode){
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(runLengthEncode.getBytes());
    try{
        imageRLE = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(runLengthEncode.getBytes()));
    }catch(IOException e){

    }
    //decode(runLengthEncode);
    if(imageRLE == null)
        System.out.println("imageRLE is null");
    return imageRLE;
}
```

Comment: Without getting into algorithms, you might want to look into [byte buffers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) for all your byte-wrangling needs.

Comment: Not sure why you dissociate "run length encoding" from "huffman"; building a Huffman tree is an example of RLE...

Comment: Huffman trees take a frequency of the values from the image as a whole and then the values which show up less are given a larger byte allocation than those that show up most, so it's dynamic allocation and has different uses to RLE. I've got to do a comparison of the two on images with different colour spaces. So have to take into account Efficiency (space and time). Compression ratio, and the quality of the image after compression(which technically shouldn't change due to lossless).

Comment: @fge: Huffman encoding is *not* RLE...

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I lack knowledge here; to my eyes, doing any form of RLE requires some sort of dictionary upfront. So, why isn't Huffman coding an example of RLE?

Comment: @fge standard RLE doesn't need a dictionary upfront, image RLE does but that's only to say whether it is using 4 bits or 8 bit to represent the runLength. RLE just checks whether a value is recurring, if it is it adds the amount the value recurrs in a row in front of said value. then removes the recurring ones. So String AAAABB when RLE compressed becomes 4A2B so going from 6 bits to 4 bits (if each Char was 1 bit). Huffman however does need a dictionary as in the above example AAAA could become just A and BB could become B. but if we had AAAABBAAA then AAA would need to be C or A2 or somethin

Comment: @fge: because Huffman doesn't encode information about the length of runs. Because Huffman maps variable-length tokens to fixed-length input chunks, whereas RLE (generally) does the opposite. etc. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use a ByteArrayOutputStream in the exact same way you use the StringBuffer:

```
public byte[] getRunLength(){
    ByteArrayOutputStream dest = new ByteArrayOutputStream();        
    for(int i =0; i < imageByteArray.length; i++){
        int runlength = 1;
        while(i+1 < imageByteArray.length && imageByteArray[i] == imageByteArray[i+1]){
            runlength++;
            i++;

        }     

        dest.write((byte)runlength);  
        dest.write((byte)imageByteArray[i]);
    }
    return dest.toByteArray();
}
```

This avoids the whole convert to char and back.

By the way, the algorithm is inefficient and probably wrong.  You iterate over each character, and then for each character you look forward for the span of characters.  You don't need to do that.  You are already walking through all the characters, so all you need to do is remember what the last character was, and ac accordingly.

```
public byte[] getRunLength(){
    ByteArrayOutputStream dest = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
    byte lastByte = imageByteArray[0];
    int matchCount = 1;
    for(int i=1; i < imageByteArray.length; i++){
        byte thisByte = imageByteArray[i];
        if (lastByte == thisByte) {
            matchCount++;
        }
        else {
            dest.write((byte)matchCount);  
            dest.write((byte)lastByte);
            matchCount=1;
            lastByte = thisByte;
        }                
    }
    dest.write((byte)matchCount);  
    dest.write((byte)lastByte);
    return dest.toByteArray();
}
```

You will see that this touches each byte value only once.

Comment: Well that seems to be working when i output the runLengthEncode to a txt file so thank you very much for that. I'm getting a null image for some reason on imageRle = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(runLengthEncode); however. I'm assuming it's something wrong with how i'm using ImageIO, or possibly the format of my byteArray. Also both have the same output, i'll get the thread runtime at some point to see which one is more time efficient.

Comment: If you like the answer, click the check mark under the answer number to indicate "accepted answer"

Comment: Note that the `getRunLength()` methods above only works as long as no run-length is longer than 255, otherwise the `runLength` or `matchCount` will overflow when stored as a byte. Java only has signed bytes so run-lengths between 128-255 will be stored as negative values, so you also need to take this into account when decoding.

Answer (score 0):

you are using flush in ByteArrayOutputStream this will give you wrong information
to make your code run just remove the line

```
public byte[] byteArray(BufferedImage image){
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] imageInByte = null;
try{
    ImageIO.write(image, "BMP", baos);

    imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
    baos.close();
}catch(IOException e){
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}

return imageInByte;
}
```